# Adding map in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

How can I append a new `Map` type in firestore?

```
void addUser() async {
    final us = _firestore.collection("users").doc(_search.text);
    us.update({
      "requests": (
        {_auth.currentUser?.email: rep}
      ),
    });
  }
```

Am using this method but the requests field in my firestore overwrites the previous one I want it to be appended. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update()` method will always overwrite your previous field with the new one, so achieving this with one operation using the `update()` is not possible, however, you can always get the current field from the document, then update its value, then save it again in the document like this:

```
void addUser() async {
    final us = _firestore.collection("users").doc(_search.text);
    final currentDoc = await us.get(); // we get the document snapshot
    final docDataWhichWeWillChange = currentDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; // we get the data of that document

    docDataWhichWeWillChange{"requests"]![_auth.currentUser?.email] = rep; // we append the new value with it's key 
    
    await us.update({
      "requests": docDataWhichWeWillChange["requests"],
    }); // then we update it again
  }
```

But you should use this after being aware that this method will make two operations in your database, a `get()` and `update()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to record multiple values, an array is an appropriate type. So, you could use the `.arrayUnion` method to record multiple entries.

```
final washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
  "regions": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["greater_virginia"]),
});
```

Comment: Hi, the `arrayUnion()` can be used on array ( `List` ), not `Map`  https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/arrayUnion.html

Comment: @Gwhyyy Mate your place, those maps in array, and you can append them like you wanted in your question.

Comment: @Mises, Hi, can you clear it for me, I don't see an array in the "requests" field in the OP's question, I would be grateful.

Comment: `.update({ "regions": FieldValue.arrayUnion([{some object...}]) })` regions are an array but what they can contain is not only text but objects to, so you can save there your Maps! Without reading the document.

Comment: Yes, this could be used as a fix for the problem, but now the `"requests"` is a List<Map>, not a Map containing key/value pairs, right? this changes the type and format of code and requires making changes and refactoring across all code that's based on it.

Comment: @Gwhyyy Mate use your imagine does this `.update({ "docMapList": FieldValue.arrayUnion([{ "requests": ({_auth.currentUser?.email: rep}) }, { "complaints": ({_auth.currentUser?.email: rep}) }]) })` will open your mind? Field/array "docMapList" updated with two new maps named "requests" and "complaints".

Comment: @Mises, I understand know, sorry, I this caused from of my lack of knowledge, thank you!